# EEG Deep Learning application with limited accuracy (around 70%) no matter the architecture

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to replicate some experiments involving EEG data and epileptic seizure detection. The dataset I've been using is a very well known one in this task, CHB MIT and I have tried a couple of different approaches, but I never seem to be able to replicate the results shown in some of the papers I've read.

I wanted to use CNN to classify raw EEG data. I have split the original signal in 2seconds segments, before this I scaled the data to have unit variance and also applied a band pass filter from 4-40HZ to remove unwanted artifacts. Since there is a very high class imbalance, I applied SMOTE to increase the minority class and undersampled the majority class. The dataset has 23 patients and I have been training on the data from all patients except 1 and doing the validation on the left out patient. The results always hoover around 70% accuracy. The main issue here is that I have used multiple architectures and now I'm using a simple MLP and I always get the 70% accuracy with the training and validation losses diverging in an overfitting manner in just a few epochs. The training accuracy is at around 98%, btw.

I am out of options. Some of the papers I read claim to have over 90% accuracy in this cross-patient task.

Here's one of my CNN architectures. I'm using keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(self.channels, WINDOW_SIZE, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(1, 10), activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (18, 8), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Reshape((16, 632, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (16, 10), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Reshape((32, 311, 1)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (32, 10), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((1, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

I don't want to convert my input data into images, like some of the papers I've read do. My idea is to use the raw data.

Some of the papers:
https://dl.acm.org/doi/fullHtml/10.1145/3241056
http://150.162.46.34:8080/icassp2019/ICASSP2019/pdfs/0001120.pdf

A small part of one of my training sessions:

Accuracy:
[image]

Loss:
[image]

Comment: Can you switch up your validation and do it on a different patient? Are you sure you are using the same dataset and network structures like in the papers you've read?

Comment: Yeah, I tried switching to other patients and the results are pretty similar. The networks and dataset are essentially the same :/

Comment: If you really want to replicate results, there is also the possibility of contacting some of the authors. They might be able to help, especially when it is apparent that their paper is not clear enough.